# How to solve getting json data with python

Tags: python

im very new in python programming, so i created the following python script in order to iterate in a folder which contain 3000 or more json files, and i dont know how to iterate in those 3000 json files to do not put manually in the script, and i need to put a specific path where are the json files located as well and i dont know how to declare it.

```
import json
all_results = {}
json_file_list = ['1.json', '2.json']
for file in json_file_list:
     with open(file) as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
       if 'result' in value:
            all_results[key] = value['result']
return all_results
```

after run my python script i have the following error :

```
File "getResult.py", line 20
  return all_results
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

and this is how looks like my jsons files

{
    "igt@gem_reloc_overflow@single-overflow": {
        "**type**": "TestResult",
        "command": "/home/gfx/intel-graphics/intel-gpu-tools/tests/gem_reloc_overflow --run-subtest single-overflow",
        "dmesg": "",
        "environment": "PIGLIT_PLATFORM=\"mixed_glx_egl\" PIGLIT_SOURCE_DIR=\"/home/gfx/intel-graphics/intel-gpu-tools/piglit\"",
        "err": "(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function reloc_tests, file gem_reloc_overflow.c:260:\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Failed assertion: **gem_execbuf(fd, &execbuf) == -14\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: error: -22 != -14\nSubtest single-overflow failed.\n**** DEBUG ****\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) DEBUG: relocation_count=4294967295\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function reloc_tests, file gem_reloc_overflow.c:260:\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Failed assertion: __gem_execbuf(fd, &execbuf) == -14\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: error: -22 != -14\n****  END  ****\n",
        "exception": null,
        "out": "IGT-Version: 1.14-g1e9a3ac (x86_64) (Linux: 4.6.0-rc4-drm-intel-nightly-ww17-commit-1e81bac+ x86_64)\nStack trace:\n  #0 [__igt_fail_assert+0x101]\n  #1 [reloc_tests+0x6d6]\n  #2 [+0x6d6]\nSubtest single-overflow: FAIL (8.469s)\n",
        "pid": 19562,
        "result": "fail",
        "returncode": 99,
        "subtests": {
            "__type**": "Subtests"
        },
        "time": {
            "**type**": "TimeAttribute",
            "end": 1462072402.5360818,
            "start": 1462072393.7328644
        },
        "traceback": null
    }
}

any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `print all_results` instead of `return all_results`.  Or you could print them one by one as they are found.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the files in a directory without having to enter the filenames manually, you can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) or [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/) for more details.

The syntax error seems pretty self-explanatory.  You have a `return` statement that is not inside of a function definition; this is invalid Python.  If you want to output the results, use `print`.

Comment: thanks, but with this command : onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))] , i have only the json files names, and i need the full path with the names because python shows me that it cant find the files

Answer (score 0):

Store the path of JSON file directory to a variable

```
mypath = "/home/json_file_directory"
```

Use os.listdir() to list all the json files.

Once you have json filename,use

```
 os.path.join(mypath,filename) #to get the exact path of file.
```